# What is a good network for full-page rich ads?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-a-script, advertising

I'm currently developing a website where users will be able to upload content. I would like to be able to show a full-page ad whenever someone tries to view the content. The ad should take up most of the screen, and I should be able to have a "continue to the content -->" link at the top. Preferably, I want something like what is currently on Forbes (if you haven't seen it, here: http://www.forbes.com/fdc/welcome.shtml but with an ad in the black area). Of course, the most revenue is the best.

Comment: adbrite? maybe them full screen ad is what you are looking for

Comment: If you inspect the HTML behind the adbox you refer to you'll be able to see which network it's on - in this case RealMedia.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an "Interstitial Ad". I didn't look into it too much, but found these two providers:

http://adclickmedia.com/m/interstitial_info.cgi/adclickmedia

http://www.clicksor.com/interstitials-ads

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance you have custom advertising, or that your current provider has larger sizes available and just not specifically this interstitial functionality, it's actually pretty simple to build yourself.

This is *much* less complicated than it looks with the list nesting; there's relatively little actual code involved. I'm just trying to keep the logic fairly clear:

1. Decide how often you want to show your interstitial. It's usually something like once every X hours.
2. Create a standalone page(eg. `insterstitial.html`) that has your ad in it, styled however you like. Forbes' [looks like this](http://www.forbes.com/fdc/welcome_mjx.shtml) at the moment; it's just a plain HTML document with some scripting(below) and code for an ad slot in it. This document has a rudimentary [Javascript timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) that sends the browser back a step in the history(See the `setTimeOut()` and `goBack()` functions in the Forbes document; you can just steal them) once expired.
3. On your story pages, you add a bit of code that checks whether a cookie called "timeout" exists.

   1. If it does not exist, create the cookie, with a value of the current timestamp and send the browser to the interstitial page. Skip to #4.
   2. If it *does* exist, you check if the difference between its value(timestamp) and the current time exceeds the interim you chose back at step 1.

      1. If no, nothing happens and the user sees the page as normal.
      2. If yes, update the cookie with the current timestamp, and redirect the browser to interstitial.html. Skip to #4.
4. For all cases where the user is sent to the interstitial, they'll watch the add or click the skip link, and then be bounced back to the refering URL(`goBack()`), at which point the timeout test will fail(step #3.2.1) and the user will be shown the page.

(The cookie and interstitial doc can obviously be named whatever you want.)